# SQL statement to get data from a week back?

Tags: c#, sql, web-applications

I am new to SQL statements and I am having a little trouble getting data from a week ago based on the date modified.

```
   SELECT People.first, People.last, company.companyname, People.lastmodified
   FROM job_prof 
   INNER JOIN People ON job_prof.cid = People.cid 
   INNER JOIN company ON job_prof.Id = company.id
-> WHERE   People.lastmodified = DATE(DATE_ADD(GETDATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY))
   ORDER BY People.lastmodified DESC";
```

Example of Date in the table is  6/9/2011 12:08:01 PM

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Thank you

Comment: What's the exact range you want? Anything modified over a week ago? Anything modified only during last week?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE  DATEDIFF(day,  People.lastmodified, GETDATE()) <= 7
```

Comment: Got It!

    WHERE  DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), People.lastmodified) >= -7


Thanks @Bara R

And

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Just remember that if you intend to ignore time, you might need to truncate the time portion in your date comparisons.

Comment: How about going back two weeks... so instead of last week it has to be two weeks prior (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021347/how-to-get-two-week-prior-data-from-a-table)

Answer (score 2):

The trick with dates is to create a range *first* with DATEADD and whatever else you need, I.e.

```
declare @start datetime = ...,
        @end datetime = ...
```

Then search in that range; I typically include the start and exclude the end, as this allows a simple "data between the 10th and 12th"

```
where row.lastmodified >= @start
and   row.lastmodified < @end
```

Having a range is critical unless the values are entire units (days, etc) - otherwise equality won't work very well. And the simple >= and < use allows effective use of indexing etc.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a range you're looking for, such as anything modified starting a week ago and ending a week before that, BETWEEN makes this pretty easy.

```
WHERE People.lastmodified BETWEEN DATEADD(week, -1, getdate()) AND DATEADD(week, -2, getdate())
```